# Fastapi how to return one field from nested model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a user model which is linked to a status model. How do I return only one field from the status model?
what i get now:

```
"status": {
        "name": "figmer",
        "id": "4"
    },
```

what I want

```
"status": "figmer"
```

My models

```
class UserBase(BaseModel):
     
    status_id: int = Field(default=1, title="status id")
    status: Union[PermissionRetrieve, str] = Field(default=..., title="status")

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class PermissionBase(BaseModel):
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class PermissionRetrieve(PermissionBase):
    id: str
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON serialiation can be customized [via `json_encoders`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#serialising-self-reference-or-other-models):

> By default, models are serialised as dictionaries. If you want to serialise them differently, you can add models_as_dict=False when calling json() method and add the classes of the model in json_encoders

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class PermissionBase(BaseModel):
    name: str


class PermissionRetrieve(PermissionBase):
    id: str


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    status_id: int = Field(default=1, title="status id")
    status: PermissionRetrieve = Field(title="status")

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            PermissionRetrieve: lambda v: v.name,
        }


user = UserBase(status=PermissionRetrieve(name="figmer", id="4"))

print(user.json(models_as_dict=False))  # prints {"status_id": 1, "status": "figmer"}
```